# Kohana 3.1 ORM: Trying to build subsequent one-to-many relationships

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, one-to-many, kohana-orm

I have a MySQL table structure that looks like this:

Countries -> Countries_Regions (FK: country_id) -> Countries_Regions_Cities (FK: region_id)

So, there's a one-to-many relationship between country and region, and there's a one-to-many relationship between region and city

I tried to link them with the following classes:

```
class Model_Country extends ORM {
    protected $_has_many = array('regions' => array("model" => "Countries_Region"));
}

class Model_Countries_Region extends ORM {
    protected $_has_many = array('cities' => array("model" => "Countries_Regions_City"));
    protected $_belongs_to = array('country' => array("model" => "Country"));
}

class Model_Countries_Regions_City extends ORM {
    protected $_belongs_to = array('region' => array("model" => "Countries_Region"));
}
```

Everything goes fine if I try to find all the regions with

```
$country = ORM::factory("country", 1);
$region = $country->regions->find_all();
```

But when I try to find all the cities bottom-up, with

```
$country = ORM::factory("country", 1);
$city = $country->regions->cities->find_all();
```

It does recognize the city property in region, but it returns an empty row with all the city values set to NULL.

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious, but I can't figure out what it is. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It does recognize the city property in region

Because `$country->regions` returns an ORM object with prepared **WHERE** statements, not a list of regions. If you call `$country->regions->find_all()`, you will get an array of regions, but after that you can access to their cities only through `foreach` loop.

There is a simple way, I think. Just add a `country_id` field to a City model and define a Belong_To relationship. So you will be able to use `$country->cities` or `$city->country` without loading regions.

Comment: Excellent reply, many thanks! Finally, it works correctly now.